# white space between divs - no css

Tags: html

Could anyone explain to me why there is whitespace between the first two div's and how to generally eliminate it? I looked in dev tools and it's not a margin or padding, its just plain white space...

Thanks!

```html
<div id="top-bar">
       BBC Navigation bar
     </div>

     <div class="content">
          <div class="red-bar">
                <div class="news-title">
                <h1>NEWS</h1>
                </div>
          </div>

</div>
```

Comment: you have actual space in between, which will also render.

Comment: Check line spacing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This come from your user agent style sheet,
containing default margin

```
h1 {
    display: block;
    font-size: 2em;
    -webkit-margin-before: 0.67em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0.67em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

## To fix it:

```
h1
{
   margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Makes total sense, thanks for answering my noob question!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the H1-Tag has a margin!

```css
h1 {
margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="top-bar">
           BBC Navigation bar
         </div>

         <div class="content">
              <div class="red-bar">
                    <div class="news-title">
                    <h1>NEWS</h1>
                    </div>
              </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: so simple ;) Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are two things that cause this:

1. *User-agent stylesheets* contain some basic styles, for example, making `h1`s large. As it happens, `h1`s are also given a margin.
2. *Margin collapsing* allows the margin of the `h1` to extend out of the containing `div`s, because those `div`s have no padding or border.

Thus, you'll see space between the `div`s, even though they aren't explicitly styled.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you check out the W3's "informative not normative" appendix on the default HTML stylesheet you'll see how those values are defined:

[image]

[https://www.quora.com/Why-do-the-default-margins-on-HTML-headers-increase-from-h1-to-h6](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html)

```html
<div id="top-bar">
       BBC Navigation bar
     </div>

     <div class="content">
          <div class="red-bar">
                <div class="news-title">
                NEWS
                </div>
          </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The white space between divs due to default H1 Margin and Padding

So what you have to do is set d Margin and Padding for H1 in your CSS or within your html

CSS

```
h1 {
padding:0;
margin:0;
```

}

or

```html
<div id="top-bar">
       BBC Navigation bar
     </div>

     <div class="content">
          <div class="red-bar">
                <div class="news-title">
                <h1 style="padding:0; margin:0;">NEWS</h1>
                </div>
          </div>

</div>
```